# Maven transitive dependency problem

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee

I have the following setup:

- `Master`: has modules `A` and `B`
- `A`: declares a dependency on `B`, `Master` as its parent
- `B`: `Master` as its parent

So basically `Master` has a parent pom which builds `A` and `B` where `A` has a dependency on `B`.

My problem is that I want to put all of the 3rd party dependencies in `B` (things like JUnit etc.).  But when I do this, `A` does have access to the dependencies declared by `B`.  Why is this happening?  I thought maven handles transitive dependencies.

Here are snippets of my poms just in case:

Master:

```
<modules>
            <module>../A</module>
            <module>../B</module>
</modules>
```

A:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Master</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <relativePath>../Master/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
 ...
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
 ...
</dependency>
```

B:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Master</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <relativePath>../Master/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
 ...
        <artifactId>JUnit</artifactId>
 ...
</dependency>
```

Why doesn't `A` have access to JUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JUnit dependency in Project B has scope 'test' then I don't believe it will be visibile as a transitive dependency in Project A.  See the table in [Maven Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism:  Dependency Scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).